# DOM doesn't rerender?

Tags: php, facebook, function

I am communicating with facebook api for getting user pages, and once I do the whole process, my html does not rerender with available pages user selected. So once the oauth process is completed, I get the pages and call the function that renders HTML - however, html changes only on page refresh. This is my code:

```
function renderSocialPage($provider = null)
{
    if (!empty($provider)) {
        $tab = $provider;
    } else {
        $tab = 'facebook';
    }

    $pageData = get_option('page_data');
    echo '<h1>Pages</h1>';

    ?>
    <div class="social-connections-wrapper" data-nav-tabs="">
        <div class="nav-tab-wrapper">
            <a href="#facebook"
               class="nav-tab<?php if ($tab == 'facebook') { ?> nav-tab-active<?php } ?>">Facebook</a>
            <a href="#google" class="nav-tab<?php if ($tab == 'google') { ?> nav-tab-active<?php } ?>">Google My
                Business</a>
        </div>

        <div id="facebook" class="tab-content" style="display:<?php echo $tab == 'facebook' ? 'block' : 'none' ?>;">
            <?php
            if (!empty($pageData)) {
                ?>
                <p>Connected pages:</p>
                <ul>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($pageData as $data) {
                        ?>
                        <li> <?= $data['name'] ?></li>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>

                <a href="#" id="facebook-connect-btn">Reconnect to facebook.</a>
                <?php
            } else {
                ?>
                <p>Connect your social accounts.</p>

                <a href="#" id="facebook-connect-btn">Connect to facebook</a>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function gcConnectReviews()
{
    $provider     = $_POST['provider'];
    $access_token = $_POST['accToken'];

    if ($provider === 'facebook') {
        $response  = wp_remote_get('https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/me/accounts?access_token='.$access_token);
        $data      = json_decode($response['body']);
        $page_data = $data->data;

        $fb_rev_data = [];

        foreach ($page_data as $data) {
            $fb_rev_data [] = [
                'id'           => $data->id,
                'name'         => $data->name,
                'access_token' => $data->access_token
            ];
        }

        add_option('page_data', '', '', 'yes');
        update_option('page_data', $fb_rev_data);
    } elseif ($provider === 'google') {
        // ... 
    }

    // so once I call this function, it should do render html with connected pages, 
    // but it does it only on refresh
    $this->renderSocialPage($provider);
}
```

Any advice on what could do the trick, or where I am wrong?

Comment: Could be an issue of WordPress internally caching such option values for the current script instance, I suppose? In `gcConnectReviews` you already got the data in `$fb_rev_data` - so you could just pass this to your `renderSocialPage` method as an extra, optional parameter? And have it only read from the page options, if nothing was passed for that additional parameter.

Comment: @misorude $fb_rev_data always changes, in debugger everything goes smoothly, everything works, only thing that is messing up is the updating HTML. I tried passing fb_rev_data same as $provider, in function, but nothing changes, it works the same.

Comment: That the HTML “doesn’t update” is rather impossible, if the data _did_ actually update. So it probably rather didn’t. Where/when are you calling `gcConnectReviews`?

Comment: @misorude it probabbly is a weird bug in my opinion, but it happens. Example: I select 3 pages, $page_data has 3 elements and I call the renderSocialPage() function, after I select 2 pages, $page_data updates correctly and calls the same function and goes through the foreach loop, however the HTML is not updated. gcConnectReviews is called after an ajax request is done in my JS file

Comment: _“I select 3 pages, $page_data has 3 elements”_ - where exactly? In your `gcConnectReviews`, where you fill that array based on your API call? The interesting part here would rather be, what it contains when you do `$pageData = get_option('page_data');` in the other function.

Comment: @misorude $pageData is an array of pages user selected to manage in the facebook oauth flow. Once that flow is done, I get access token so I can use facebook graph api. If the provider is facebook, it gets added to wp_options table as page_data, thats what is in gcConnectReviews function.

Comment: All of that is clear already … I asked you to _check_ what `$pageData = get_option('page_data');` inside of `renderSocialPage` actually returned.

Comment: @misorude it returns the same array of pages

Comment: And you verified this via a debug output in the same script instance, that also creates the UL in the HTML, where you are missing entries? Again, that is really rather impossible. Have you checked the generated HTML source code, to make sure nothing gets hidden from you due to some rogue CSS maybe? Do you have any caching plugins active that could interfere with this at some point or other?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208112/discussion-between-nemanja-g-and-misorude).

Comment: _“gcConnectReviews is called after an ajax request is done in my JS file”_ - where is the code for that part? Maybe you messed up correctly inserting the received response into the current document somehow? Check the response to that AJAX request in the network panel, and verify whether all pages are listed correctly at that point or not.